# regular expression matching a certain url

Tags: regex

I hate posting questions like this one, but I really suck at regex and if an expert out there can give me a quick solution I would greatly appreciate it.

I need a regular expression to match a url pattern like this one

```
https://mywebsite.com/foo/[a-z]/[a-z]/[0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9]
```

- where [a-z] means any word and both 1st and 2nd [a-z] are optional (slash also optional)
- and [0-9] mean any number, but all three [0-9] are mandatory
  and nothing should be following the third [0-9]

Matching examples:

- https://mywebsite.com/foo/bar/zoo/10/20/30
- https://mywebsite.com/foo/zoo/15/25/35
- https://mywebsite.com/foo/20/30/123

NOT matching examples:

- https://mywebsite.com/foo/bar/zoo/10/20/30/buu
- https://mywebsite.com/bar/15/25/35
- https://mywebsite.com/foo/20/30

HELP!

Comment: You posted what you want :/ You cannot decide what's `[a-z]`, it has a very particular meaning.

Comment: what do you mean by `[a-z]`? a single character?

Comment: Can you post some examples of matching and non-matching inputs?

Comment: add examples of matching and not matching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
https:\/\/mywebsite\.com\/foo(?:\/[a-z]+){0,2}(?:\/[0-9]+){3}
```

Add anchors if necessary.

```
^https:\/\/mywebsite\.com\/foo(?:\/[a-z]+){0,2}(?:\/[0-9]+){3}$
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/rC2mH4/5)

Range quantifier `{0,2}` in `(?:\/[a-z]+){0,2}` repeats the previous token that is `/[a-z]+`, zero or one or two times.

Comment: https shouldn't be optional :-)

Comment: Was my mistake in the matching/not-matching examples to omiss https, edited now!

Answer (score 0):

With "number" do you mean digit or number?
I'm assuming you mean number.

This matches your request:

`/^https:\/\/mywebsite\.com\/foo\/[a-z]*\/[a-z]*\/\d+\/\d+\/\d+$/`

however when you write "1st and 2nd [a-z] are optional" I guess you mean the slashes that follow them should also be optional. If that's the case then use this:

`/^https:\/\/mywebsite\.com\/foo\/([a-z]+\/)?([a-z]+\/)?\/\d+\/\d+\/\d+$/`

The `$` at the end makes sure that nothing else follows.